# "Go Green !" : Grammatical Analysis

Tags: meaning, etymology, grammaticality, cliche

I have been trying to see what is behind the hyped-up phrase "**Go Green**" and have asked friends to rephrase that buzz-word/cliche, but nobody has given me a satisfactory explanation of what it actually means, in terms of grammar.

When I searched Google for "**Go Green & Grammar**", I got webpages where they are trying to spread Environmental messages, while teaching English. When I searched for "**etymology of go green**", I got a wiki entry for "Gringo". When I searched for "**what does it mean to go green**", I got "Going green means implementing certain lifestyle changes designed to help you live in a more eco-friendly way". I get all this, but I want to know about the **grammatical correctness and analysis and etymology**.

So here I am , on ELU, asking about it.

I see business PR statements like, "Every year, we have been conducting this event, but this year we decided to **go green**".

Specifically, I have two Doubts (1) What is the grammatical & Etymological Deconstruction of the sentence "Go Green !" or the phrase ". . . go green . . ." ? & (2) What is one actually supposed to do to "go green" ?

Is it a hyped-up buzz-word/cliche devoid of meaning ? Are we currently in some other colour and we have to physically move to some green zone ?

I thought , maybe translating between languages will help. So I converted "go green" to French to get "mettre au vert" and back to English to get "go green". Now I converted "mettre au bleu" to get "put blue" and "mettre au rouge" to get "put red". It seems (from this very small inconclusive experiment) that the "go green" hype has entered French too, such that some colours "go", while other colours "put".

Comment: I'm not sure what your problem is, Prem. To "go" some ideology like environmental is pretty established in English. Think of the way the Americans used to fuss about how some country, perhaps including yours, was in danger of "going Communist". It's the same usage.

Comment: @DavidPugh , "going Communist" might be a shortening of "going [in] the Communist way" or "becoming a Communist Country" and so it has a way of rephrasing. Though you may be right about it, I have not come across a rephrasing of "go green" as "go in the green way", but even that rephrasing seems to be a buzzword way of speaking.

Comment: The colour *green* is, unremarkably, associated with the environment, and so it is often used as a short, catchy synonym for the more cumbersome phrase *environmentally friendly*. *To go* can often be a synonym for *to become*, as in *to go insane*. So, one might rephrase *we've decided to go green* as *we've decided to become environmentally friendly*. In terms of grammar, *to go* is (counter-intuitively) behaving like a copular verb and *green* is a predicate adjective. As for whether the idiom *to go green* has lost its meaning and become little more than a buzz-phrase, who knows?

Comment: @Anonym . good points. So "Go Green !" is "Be Environment Friendly !" , in many cases. Both "Go" and "Green" do not take the common meanings here. I think this is a case of a "Double Metaphor".

Comment: @Prem There is only one metaphor here: green = trees and grass = unspoiled nature = environmentally friendly. As others have said, one common meaning of *go* is *become* (as an imperative).

Comment: @DanBron , here "green" is a metaphor. In WordWeb, the entry for "go" says "Change location; proceed; also used metaphorically" with an example as "The policemen went from door to door looking for the suspect". So, "go" is also a metaphor, because we do not literally move to "green", from other colour, say "gray".

Comment: @Prem Nah. If you say "He's a very *green guy*" the *is* is not figurative even though you're not describing his skin color. If you say "That company is taking up a number of *green initiatives*", the *taking up* is not metaphorical even though the initiatives are not printed on green pieces of paper. In those two examples, just like in "*Go Green!*", there is only one metaphor (that green=environmentally conscious); the other words are just contributing their standard meanings and functions to that one metaphor. As *go*=*become* is.

Comment: @DanBron , yes "go" looks like the normal usage, but if "go green" refers not only to "become" but to "embrace" & "monetise" & "popularise", then would it be a metaphor ? What I mean : suppose a company saying "go green" remains the same internally, but externally, it sells products [monetise] to the"environmentally friendly" market, or it prints magazines [popularise] on "environmentally friendly topics" but a hazardous printing process is used, or the CEO stops cribbing about "environmentally friendly laws" and unwillingly wants to just meet the regulations [embrace]. Am I making sense ?

Comment: @Prem It sounds to me like you the slogan "go green" rings hypocritical to you. I'm absolutely certain that some people who have used it have used it hypocritically. But I'm just as certain that others have used it sincerely: with genuine ardor and sympathy for the cause. And neither of those acts is specific to this slogan. Any political or ethical utterance has, does, and will have people sincere about it & others merely paying it lip service. In other words: this isn't about grammar, it's about people. Outside of the "green=eco-friendly" metaphor, there's nothing unusual about *go green*.

Comment: @DanBron , thanks , I now realise that most people who wrongly rationalise any habit/action/situation with "go green" slogans, either do so without knowing that "go" means "become", or do so hypocritically, or do so because it is in fashion, or a combination of these cases. I now have clarity on both the language issues as well as the psychological issues.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, *green* is a modern metaphor for *environmentally conscious*.

*go* is being used per definition #4 in [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/go):

> [NO OBJECT, WITH COMPLEMENT] Pass into or be in a specified state, especially an undesirable one

although in this case whether it's considered "undesirable" likely depends on your political persuasion.

In recent years, I think this sense of *go* has become popular in pithy phrases, as in the aphorism *Once you go black, you never go back* (meaning that once a white person has had sex with a black person, they won't be satisfied with whites any more), although the rhyme probably also contributes to the popularity of this example.

Comment: +1, I am getting a lot of clarity from the comments by DanBron & Anonym & DavidPugh. Your answer supports those comments.

Answer (score 1):

"Go Green!" means either "You should become more green", or "Team Green go!".

Dealing with the second version first, "Green" would be the colors adopted by a sports team and you would be encouraging them to win.

But "go green" in the first version is entirely different.  "Green" is the color which, by convention, is associated with environmental concerns, and "going green" means to become more "environmentally conscious".

Depending on the context, this may imply simply trying to burn less gasoline, or it may imply divesting yourself of all "non-green" investments, installing a solar array on your house, and eating only "sustainably grown" food.

As to the syntax of the sentence "Go green", for the team cheer it's simply an inversion of subject and verb -- "[Team] Green go".  For the enviromental exhortation it's an imperative sentence with an understood subject and verb -- "[You should] go green".

Comment: +1, I am getting a lot of clarity from the comments by DanBron & Anonym & DavidPugh. Your answer supports those comments.

Answer (score 0):

"Go Green" could also mean "**go green with envy**, extremely jealous" e.g. "Digsy's Diner" by Oasis. "*...And then your friends will all go green
for my lasagne*"

Comment: In another direction, "green" could mean sick, nauseated. People could go green *from* my lasagna.